# Tekton - mount path workspace issue - Error of path

Tags: tekton, tekton-pipelines

Currently, I am trying to deploy tutum-hello-world. I have written a script for the same, but it does not work as it is supposed to.
I am certain that this issue is related to workspace.

**UPDATE**
Here is my code for `task-tutum-deploy.yaml`-

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: tutum-deploy
spec:
  steps:
    - name: tutum-deploy
      image: bitnami/kubectl
      script: |
        kubectl apply -f /root/tekton-scripts/tutum-deploy.yaml
  workspaces:
    - name: messages
      optional: true
      mountPath: /root/tekton-scripts/
```

Error -

```
root@master1:~/tekton-scripts# tkn taskrun logs tutum-deploy-run-8sq8s -f -n default
[tutum-deploy] + kubectl apply -f /root/tekton-scripts/tutum-deploy.yaml
[tutum-deploy] error: the path "/root/tekton-scripts/tutum-deploy.yaml" cannot be accessed: stat /root/tekton-scripts/tutum-deploy.yaml: permission denied

container step-tutum-deploy has failed  : [{"key":"StartedAt","value":"2021-06-14T12:54:01.096Z","type":"InternalTektonResult"}]
```

PS - I have placed my script on the master node at - `/root/tekton-scripts/tutum-deploy.yaml`

```
root@master1:~/tekton-scripts# ls -l tutum-deploy.yaml 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 626 Jun 11 11:31 tutum-deploy.yaml
```

**OLD SCRIPT**

Here is my code for `task-tutum-deploy.yaml`-

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: tutum-deploy
spec:
  workspaces:
    - name: messages
      optional: true
      mountPath: /root/tekton-scripts/tutum-deploy.yaml
  steps:
    - name: tutum-deploy
      image: bitnami/kubectl
      command: ["kubectl"]
      args:
        - "apply"
        - "-f"
        - "./tutum-deploy.yaml"
```

Here is my code for `tutum-deploy.yaml` which is present on the machine (master node) of Kubernetes cluster with read, write and execute permissions -

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world-tutum
  labels:
    service: hello-world-tutum
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      service: hello-world-tutum
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        service: hello-world-tutum
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tutum-hello-world
        image: tutum/hello-world:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-world-tutum
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    service: hello-world-tutum
  ports:
  - name: "80"
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30050
```

I ran the following commands from my master node of Kubernetes cluster -

```
1. kubectl apply -f task-tutum-deploy.yaml

2. tkn task start tutum-deploy
```

Error -

Using tekton command - `$ tkn taskrun logs tutum-deploy-run-tvlll -f -n default`

```
task tutum-deploy has failed: "step-tutum-deploy" exited with code 1 (image: "docker-pullable://bitnami/kubectl@sha256:b83299ee1d8657ab30fb7b7925b42a12c613e37609d2b4493b4b27b057c21d0f"); for logs run: kubectl -n default logs tutum-deploy-run-tvlll-pod-vbl5g -c step-tutum-deploy

[tutum-deploy] error: the path "./tutum-deploy.yaml" does not exist

container step-tutum-deploy has failed  : [{"key":"StartedAt","value":"2021-06-11T14:01:49.786Z","type":"InternalTektonResult"}]
```

Comment: Before `kubectl` command in the task, can you try `ls` to see what files exists in the path? Have you placed the deployment manifest there?

Comment: `ls` gives me the following  output-

`# tkn taskrun logs tutum-deploy-run-nz6qt -f -n default`
`[tutum-deploy] + ls`
`[tutum-deploy] bin`
`[tutum-deploy] boot`
`[tutum-deploy] dev`
`[tutum-deploy] etc`
`[tutum-deploy] home`
`[tutum-deploy] lib`
`[tutum-deploy] lib64`
`[tutum-deploy] media`
`[tutum-deploy] mnt`
`[tutum-deploy] opt`
`[tutum-deploy] proc`
`[tutum-deploy] root`
`[tutum-deploy] run`
`[tutum-deploy] sbin`
`[tutum-deploy] srv`
`[tutum-deploy] sys`
`[tutum-deploy] tekton`
`[tutum-deploy] tmp`
`[tutum-deploy] usr`
`[tutum-deploy] var`
`[tutum-deploy] workspace'

Answer (score 1):

The error is from this part of your YAML:

```yaml
spec:
  workspaces:
    - name: messages
      optional: true
      mountPath: /root/tekton-scripts/tutum-deploy.yaml
```

`spec.workspaces.mountPath` expects a directory, rather than a file, as you have specified here. You may mean `/root/tekton-scripts/` instead but I am unfamiliar with `tutum-hello-world`.

If you look at [the documentation](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/blob/main/docs/workspaces.md) you will see that all references to `mountPath` are directories rather than files.

Comment: Even after using mounPath. It has some permission issues. Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Post the permissions issues and happy to try to help 

Comment: I have edited my post with latest error. Please see my post. 
fyr, here is the permission issues - 
```[tutum-deploy] error: the path "/root/tekton-scripts/tutum-deploy.yaml" cannot be accessed: stat /root/tekton-scripts/tutum-deploy.yaml: permission denied```

and this is the permission level of the file - 
```-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 626 Jun 11 11:31 tutum-deploy.yaml```

Comment: The permissions error here could be anywhere in the path. Although you own the file, you may not have the correct permissions in `/root/tekton-scripts/` or `/root`.